# Querying a table based on another table's value

Tags: android, sqlite, serialization

So this is the general flow of my app:

`Main Menu` -> `Account Manager` -> `Account Details` -> `Payment Schedule`

The data from the user's selection in `Account Manager` is passed to `Account Details` through a `Serialized Object`. Then from `Account Details` the same `Serialized Object` is then passed to `Payment Schedule` for calculation purposes and all the results are thrown into my database specifically into `PayTable`.

Each account can have multiple payments so to make sure I can associate the proper payment entries to the proper account I have a `GroupID` in my `PayTable`. So now entries into `PayTable` are assigned a `GroupID` which is based on the `AccountID` in `AccountsTable` passed to `Payment Schedule`.

So if `AccountID = 1` then `GroupID = 1`.

Using this I can filter out the proper payments for the proper account and then  display them in my `GridView` in `Payments Schedule`.

**EDIT ( Removed most of the old post that didn't matter anymore but left the gist of my situation up top for reference )**

**Summary**

I had two tables `Account` and `Payment`. `Account` had `colID` and `Payment` had `GroupID`. `GroupID` was dependent on the `colID` of the account selected. So if `colID` was say 3 all payment entries during that instance would also be assigned a `GroupID` of 3 so I could pair the proper payments to the right account.

Problem being I needed to compare the two fields (`GroupID` == `colID` ) and get all the entries that would match the condition. So this meant a cross comparison of two fields from two tables.

**Solution**

1. Used INNER JOIN and created a view for easier GridView reference:

   ```
   db.execSQL("CREATE VIEW " + viewPayments +
                   " AS SELECT " + payTable + "." + colPayID + " AS _id," +
                   " " + accountsTable + "." + colID + "," +
                   " " + payTable + "." + colGroupID + "," +
                   " " + payTable + "." + colPayBal + "," +
                   " " + payTable + "." + colInterest + "," +
                   " " + payTable + "." + colPayDue + "," +
                   " " + payTable + "." + colDateDue + "," +
                   " " + payTable + "." + colPaid + "" +
                   " FROM " + payTable +
                   " JOIN " + accountsTable + " ON " + payTable + "." + colGroupID + " = " + accountsTable + "." + colID );
   ```
2. Fixed my query

   ```
   Cursor filterpay(String Payment) {
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       String[] columns = new String[]{"_id", colGroupID, colPayBal, colInterest, colPayDue, colDateDue, colPaid};
       Cursor c = db.query(viewPayments, columns, colGroupID + "=?", new String[]{Payment}, null, null, null);
       return c;
   ```
3. Last but not least, adjust my code for posting on my GridView.

   ```
   TextView txt;
   txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.putithere);
   txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);

   public void Paygrid(){

   dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
   String Payment = String.valueOf(txt.getText());
   Cursor a = dbHelper.filterpay(Payment);
   startManagingCursor(a);

   String[] from = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.colPayBal, DatabaseHelper.colInterest, DatabaseHelper.colPayDue, DatabaseHelper.colDateDue, DatabaseHelper.colPaid};
   int[] to = new int[]{R.id.Amount,R.id.Interest, R.id.Total, R.id.DateDue, R.id.Paid};

   SimpleCursorAdapter saa = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.paygrid, a, from, to);
   intgrid.setAdapter(saa);
   ```

   }

The `txt` stuff was just me being lazy to find a cleaner way to get the `colID` of the Account and reference it in my 'PayGrid' so I probably won't recommend following me in that regard.

Also since I'm new here so I don't know how to mark this question as answered when I answer my own question so if someone could point that out that would nice. That aside I hope this helps someone in the future. Cheers.

On a side note, thanks for the downvote random person! Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: first where: `" WHERE (" + colGroupID + "=? OR 1=?)"` next params: for all: `new String[]{"0", "1"}` for specific groupid `new String[]{GroupId, "0"}`

Comment: I'm not seeing where you're passing the GroupID or AccountID to your query.

Comment: Why is this `new String[]{}` **empty**? You aren't passing your parameter...

Comment: Sorry about that, I must've overwritten that part when I was copy-pasting codes. I edited and marked it as a NOTE now. Again, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just saw the "Answer your question" button at the bottom of the page RIGHT AFTER I edited and posted my own solution.... yes, I did facepalm when I did.

**Solution**

1. Used INNER JOIN and created a view for easier GridView reference:

   ```
   db.execSQL("CREATE VIEW " + viewPayments +
                   " AS SELECT " + payTable + "." + colPayID + " AS _id," +
                   " " + accountsTable + "." + colID + "," +
                   " " + payTable + "." + colGroupID + "," +
                   " " + payTable + "." + colPayBal + "," +
                   " " + payTable + "." + colInterest + "," +
                   " " + payTable + "." + colPayDue + "," +
                   " " + payTable + "." + colDateDue + "," +
                   " " + payTable + "." + colPaid + "" +
                   " FROM " + payTable +
                   " JOIN " + accountsTable + " ON " + payTable + "." + colGroupID + " = " + accountsTable + "." + colID );
   ```
2. Fixed my query

   ```
   Cursor filterpay(String Payment) {
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       String[] columns = new String[]{"_id", colGroupID, colPayBal, colInterest, colPayDue, colDateDue, colPaid};
       Cursor c = db.query(viewPayments, columns, colGroupID + "=?", new String[]{Payment}, null, null, null);
       return c;
   ```
3. Last but not least, adjust my code for posting on my GridView.

   ```
   TextView txt;
   txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.putithere);
   txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);

   public void Paygrid(){

   dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
   String Payment = String.valueOf(txt.getText());
   Cursor a = dbHelper.filterpay(Payment);
   startManagingCursor(a);

   String[] from = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.colPayBal, DatabaseHelper.colInterest, DatabaseHelper.colPayDue, DatabaseHelper.colDateDue, DatabaseHelper.colPaid};
   int[] to = new int[]{R.id.Amount,R.id.Interest, R.id.Total, R.id.DateDue, R.id.Paid};

   SimpleCursorAdapter saa = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.paygrid, a, from, to);
   intgrid.setAdapter(saa);
   ```

   }

The `txt` stuff was just me being lazy to find a cleaner way to get the `colID` of the Account and reference it in my `PayGrid` so I probably won't recommend following me in that regard.